# Schedule an IntentService

Tags: android

In my application I have an IntentService that reads rss feeds. I would like this operation to be done every 30 minutes. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setInexactRepeating in AlarmManager. It saves some battery.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: Wouldn't that consume the battery? If so, I was wondering if there is a way of running the service only when the application is in foreground.

Comment: Some. You can cancel the alarm on onPaused -event if you really want to do so.